# Memory: Java vs C++ vs JS

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management, browser

I have a question about how each of these languages (js/c(c++)/java) handles memory.

I know that C and it's derivatives are able to do direct memory management through pointers and functions that revolve around the concept such as "malloc".

I also know that Java runs in it's own JRE, which to my understanding is a virtual machine. To clarify, the bytecode produced is the jre equivalent to the executable that is produced from C source code for an O.S.? If this helps explain to a better extent

- Java -> source code compiled to bytecode -> runs in JRE
- C -> source code compiled to executable -> runs in O.S.

My question is that I know that JS and Java are not related at all. What I've heard is that when naming the language in the 90's, Netscape just hopped onto the Sun's Java bandwagon. However, each browser requires a JS Engine, for example, Google Chrome's V8 JS Engine. When you declare and assign variable, because js is client side, does this piece of memory come from the memory allotted on the system for the browser? And to further this, is this memory allotted for the variables inside of the memory allotted for the runtime environment in the memory for the browser?

I hope the way I'm phrasing this makes sense.

Comment: This is dated, but may give a starting point, as each javascript engine will do things somewhat differently: http://www.phreedom.org/research/heap-feng-shui/heap-feng-shui.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The javascript engine is part of the browser (in this case. javascript can be executed in other non-browser environments. Google's V8, for example, is also inside Node.js). The browser acts as the `Host environment` for javascript. Javascript, on its own, is a very limited language (when its default API is concerned). Is the Host environment, the browser, what gives javascript acces to the DOM and other HTML APIs. Similarly, JScript, in Windows, gets access to some functionality exposed by COM, and, in Node.js, a server API.

Basically, when you create new objects in javascript, javascript asks for memory from the browswer, and the browser asks the Operating System for it.

You can test this easily:

```
var array = [];
var str = 'a simple string that occupies a bit of memory, though not too much.';
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    array.push(str + '(' + i + ')');
}
```

Execute this inside a browser, open the Task Manager and you'll se the memory usage of the browser grow.